# vb.net special permutation of array

Tags: vb.net, permutation

Let's says I have an array that consists of string like

```
array = "C-F-A-M"
```

Instead of common permutation's formulas like

```
**n! / (n-r)**
```

I want the result of array permutation is like this

```
C-M
F-M
A-M
C-A-M
C-F-M
A-F-M
```

My questions is, is there a formulas to create a permutation like that? In vb.net, is there a special method that can create a permutation?

I don't ask for a codes or something, I'm just asking about formulas.

Comment: An array is not a string.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs to [Math.SE]